# Make FLASK API run for each part of a JSON

Tags: python, json, flask, flask-restful

I have this FLASK API that receives a JSON through a POST and runs a local exe with parameters from the JSON, now here is how the json looks like :

```json
{
    "albumID": "4321",
    "folderID": "test",
    "subfolderID": "test1",
    "pictures": [
        {
            "pic": "jpg.;1",
            "picname": "flower",
            "typeID": 2
        },
        {
            "pic": "png.;2",
            "picname": "mountain",
            "typeID": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

My code:

```py
for x in range(len(payload["components"])):
    data = {
        "picID": payload["picID"],
        "subfolderID": payload["subfolderID"],
        "pictures": payload["pictures"][x],
    }
```

Now my Python code would run a line like this with the received values :

```py
os.system(('cmd /c pic_sizer.exe -s '+subfolderID+' -f "'+folderID+'" -p '+picID+' -pn'+picname+' -t'+typeID))
```

I would like the API to run for each instance of pictures, you see in the JSON above I have two but it can have 2 it can have 8,9 etc, so now my question is how would I do this ? Thank you.

Comment: In you flask code, you can parse the incoming POST body with [json lib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). The `pictures` is an array type. Iterate it, extract `pic` id and call the exe with parsed data. Do you have any specific question or error?

Comment: Hey, so I managed to split them with the following code `for x in range(len(payload["components"])):
    data = {
        "picID": payload["picID"],
        "subfolderID": payload["subfolderID"],
        "pictures": payload["pictures"][x],  }` but I do not know how to get the picname and typeID now, It splits them but I'd like to get them one by one something like  "picID": payload["picID"].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Azhar Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2847330/azhar-khan) mentioned, you can iterate over the `pictures` list, extract the necessary information and run the command:

```
for picture_info in data['pictures']:
    picID = picture_info['pic'].split(';')[1]
    os.system(f"cmd /c pic_sizer.exe -s {data['subfolderID']} -f '{data['folderID']}' -p {picID} -pn {picture_info['picname']} -t {picture_info['typeID']}")
```

I wasn't sure where the `picID` value was coming from, since there is no `picID` key in the JSON, so I made an assumption that it is in each picture object, within the `pic` field right after the `;`.

Comment: Yes you are correct and this seems like the right way to do it but I get the following error "string indices must be integers, not 'str'", any ideas how I could bypass this ?

Comment: @Kano Hard to say why without looking at the code. Can you share what you have so far?

Comment: I managed to fix it, sorry for the delay, I called Pictures as a key and they used each row to execute my command, thank you for the help :D.

Comment: Nice. No worries. You welcome